# Is there a way to transform yaml properties to ConfigMap structure with Helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, configmap

I have `values.yaml` file with a number of properties, however, the application related properties are all under `application` node in the YAML file and with exact same hierarchy that they defined in Spring Boot property. See the following example:

```
imagePullPolicy: some-policy
imagePullSecret: some-secret

application:
  database:
    jdbcUrl: some url
  s3:
    bucketName: some bucket name
    subDirectory: some name
```

Now, I can declare all these properties in my `ConfigMap` as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "helper.app-name" . }}-config
data:
  database.jdbcUrl: {{ .Values.application.database.jdbcUrl }}
  s3.bucketName: {{ .Values.application.s3.bucketName }}
```

However, I was thinking if there is a way with `Helm` to pull everything under `application` and make it like a data map in my `ConfigMap` like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "helper.app-name" . }}-config
data:
  {{ some code to pull from "application" }}
```

Comment: I ended up mounting the values as a YAML file: `application-configmap.yaml: |-
    {{- .Values.application | toYaml | nindent 4 }}`

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way in Helm to do this.  The particular trick is that you are trying to flatten the YAML object hierarchy and put JSONPath-style names as dictionary keys.

You can write a recursive template function to do this.  The template needs to take two arguments (this is a little tricky), a path (prefix) and a value.  If the value is a string, write out the value as-is; if it's a map, then iterate through the map, add each key to the end of the path, and recurse.

```
{{- define "application-data" -}}
{{- if kindIs "map" .data -}}
{{- range $k, $v := .data -}}
{{- $path := list .path $k | compact | join "." -}}
{{- include "application-data" (dict "path" $path "data" $v) -}}
{{- else -}}
{{ .path }}: {{ .data }}
{{ end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

The one important trick here is that a template only takes a single parameter, which is assigned to the special variable `.`.  We pass a dictionary here; you can see that constructed in the recursive call with a `dict` with two values.  Then `.path` and `.data` within the template refer to the fields in this dictionary.

Constructing `$path` is also interesting.  It's possible for `.path` to be empty, in which case we don't want a leading `.`.  So we construct a list of the parent (possibly empty) `.path` and the per-item key; we `compact` it to remove the empty item; and we `join` the (one or two) parts together with periods.

When you call this from the top-level ConfigMap, you need to pass an empty prefix and the relevant part of the Helm values.

```yaml
data:
{{ include "application-data" (dict "path" "" "data" .Values.application) | indent 2 }}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. To be honest, I didn't try it because I needed to get it working urgently so I ended up mounting them as a file: `application-configmap.yaml: |-
    {{- .Values.application | toYaml | nindent 4 }}`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "helper.app-name" . }}-config
data:
  {{- .Values.application | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
```

Comment: But that brings the properties in the same format which then breaks the ConfigMap. I get this error if I do that `invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMap.data: got "map", expected "string"`